# Vuetify vuetify-lazy-image

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Для реализации ленивой загрузки изображений установил vuetify-lazy-image

Сделал все как описано здесь: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetify-lazy-image

То есть, сначала npm install vuetify-lazy-image, затем зарегистрировал компонент локально:

```
import VuetifyLazyImage from "vuetify-lazy-image";

export default {
  components: {
    VuetifyLazyImage
  }
};
```

В разметке это выглядит следующим образом:

В итоге в консоль выскакивает ошибка следующего содержания:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: v-img - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.

По факту ничего не работает. Но не совсем понятно, причем тег тут v-img от Vuetify? Ведь он у меня вообще не используется в разметке. С чем это может быть связанно и как устранить проблему?